# PHP I give breaks when I enter a text to store on data but when I pull it shows horizontal

Tags: php, css

I want it to show it as I store on the database

[I store like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHJAH.png)

[It Shows This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMsQf.png)

Comment: can you share print code?

Comment: Remember, we know only what you tell us about your situation, and you have not told us much apart from the probelm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a good duplicate but I'm sure there is one.  There are at least two options:

Display it in `pre` tags to display the newlines:

```
echo "<pre>{$row['com_detay']}</pre>";
```

Or convert the newlines to `br` for display in HTML:

```
echo nl2br($row['com_detay']);
```

Comment: <pre><?php echo $yorumcek['yorum_detay'] ?></pre>

 this did work for me thank you very much